# Executing a shell script using python's paramiko library

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to execute a shell script with command line arguments using python's paramiko library and the code is as shown below.

```
import paramiko

ip = input("Enter the ip address of the machine: ")
mac = input("Enter the mac address of the machine: ")
model = input("Enter the model of the box(moto/wb): ")
spec = input("Enter the spec of the box(A/B/C/CI/D/E): ")

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect('hostname', username='xxxx', password='yyyy')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('ls -l')

for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line, end = "")

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('./name.sh'+ ip+ model + spec+ mac)

for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line, end = "")

print('finished.')
```

I am not getting the output of second execute command. Instead directly it is jumping to finished. May i know how to get the output of the command execution?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting output because there is none.  Your command is not valid, so the shell fails.  The only output is sent to stderr, which you do not print.

Details:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('./name.sh'+ ip+ model + spec+ mac)
```

Assuming the user put these values:

```
ip: 111.222.333.444
model: wb
spec: C
mac: 28:d2:33:e6:4e:73
```

Then your command is:

```
./name.sh111.222.333.444wbC28:d2:33:e6:4e:73
```

Everything is appended with no spaces in between.  Simple fix:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('./name.sh "' + ip + '" "' + model + '" "' + spec + '" "' + mac + '"')
```

Your command will now be:

```
./name.sh "111.222.333.444" "wb" "C" "28:d2:33:e6:4e:73"
```

I put the `"` around the values to ensure it will work even if the user puts spaces in the values.

Or store your 4 variables into a list and the `join()` function (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/) to build your command.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But after this, i have to control that session as the command will ask me for inputs. How to do that?

Comment: Look at https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-python/ or other sites that explain that.